# Permission denied errors in Docker (even as root)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi

I am new to Docker, (recently became a fan after looking at its ease and simplicity)
But now I am struggling with this annoying error - "Permission denied"

My system: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Docker version : Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
Docker compose: Docker Compose version v2.18.1
My server is in cloud: and i ssh into it as root and running any command as root.

I am trying to install apache Nifi and Nifi registry in docker containers using a docker compose. I am trying to take help from this blog: https://medium.com/geekculture/host-a-fully-persisted-apache-nifi-service-with-docker-ffaa6a5f54a3

Since I am a root user, I am assuming i should never get permission errors, but i am getting these poermission denied errors all the time.

```
nifi_container_persistent           | 08:16:23,633 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[APP_FILE] - openFile(/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log (Permission denied)
```

When docker running as root user and the container is owned by it why would i get permission errors ? Is the error misleading ? and there is something else i am missing ?

Is this related to volumes ? and persistancy? but the main purpose of docker is to build once and run anywhere, but why these permission issues an exception ?

Your help and suggestions are much appreciated as i spent almost a day with no clue of resolution.

docker compose as mentioned in the blog:

```
version: "3"
services:
    # configuration manager for NiFi
    zookeeper:
        hostname: myzookeeper
        container_name: zookeeper_container_persistent
        image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:3.7.0'  # latest image as of 2021-11-09.
        restart: on-failure
        environment:
            - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
        networks:
            - my_persistent_network
# version control for nifi flows
    registry:
        hostname: myregistry
        container_name: registry_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi-registry:1.15.0'  # latest image as of 2021-11-09.
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
            - "18080:18080"
        environment:
            - LOG_LEVEL=INFO
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_DB_DIR=/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_FLOW_PROVIDER=file
            - NIFI_REGISTRY_FLOW_STORAGE_DIR=/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/flow_storage
        volumes:
            - ./nifi_registry/database:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database
            - ./nifi_registry/flow_storage:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/flow_storage
        networks:
            - my_persistent_network
# data extraction, transformation and load service
    nifi:
        hostname: mynifi
        container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi:1.14.0'  # latest image as of 2021-11-09.
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
            - '8091:8080'
        environment:
            - NIFI_WEB_HTTP_PORT=8080
            - NIFI_CLUSTER_IS_NODE=true
            - NIFI_CLUSTER_NODE_PROTOCOL_PORT=8082
            - NIFI_ZK_CONNECT_STRING=myzookeeper:2181
            - NIFI_ELECTION_MAX_WAIT=30 sec
            - NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY='12345678901234567890A'
        healthcheck:
            test: "${DOCKER_HEALTHCHECK_TEST:-curl localhost:8091/nifi/}"
            interval: "60s"
            timeout: "3s"
            start_period: "5s"
            retries: 5
        volumes:
            - ./nifi/database_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/database_repository
            - ./nifi/flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/flowfile_repository
            - ./nifi/content_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/content_repository
            - ./nifi/provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/provenance_repository
            - ./nifi/state:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/state
            - ./nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
            # uncomment the next line after copying the /conf directory from the container to your local directory to persist NiFi flows
            #- ./nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf
        networks:
            - my_persistent_network
networks:
  my_persistent_network:
    driver: bridge
```

some main errors from log:

```
nifi_container_persistent       | 09:16:56,261 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[APP_FILE] - openFile(/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log (Permission denied)

nifi_container_persistent       |   at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-app.log (Permission denied)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.end(AppenderAction.java:90)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:417)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:362)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.<init>(RunNiFi.java:139)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi.main(RunNiFi.java:239)
nifi_container_persistent       | 09:16:56,261 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]

nifi_container_persistent       | 09:16:56,267 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[USER_FILE] - openFile(/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log (Permission denied)

nifi_container_persistent       |   at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-bootstrap.log (Permission denied)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
nifi_container_persistent       |   at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)

registry_container_persistent   | org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLNonTransientException: IO Exception: null [90028-199]
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)

registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file nio:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db [1.4.199/1]
registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db (Permission denied)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)

registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file nio:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db [1.4.199/1]
registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db (Permission denied)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'standardServiceFacade' defined in file [/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-1.15.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/apache/nifi/registry/web/service/StandardServiceFacade.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registryService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-1.15.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/nifi-registry-framework-1.15.0.jar!/org/apache/nifi/registry/service/RegistryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseMetadataService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-1.15.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/nifi-registry-framework-1.15.0.jar!/org/apache/nifi/registry/db/DatabaseMetadataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain connection from Flyway DataSource

registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registryService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-1.15.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/nifi-registry-framework-1.15.0.jar!/org/apache/nifi/registry/service/RegistryService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseMetadataService' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/work/jetty/nifi-registry-web-api-1.15.0.war/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/nifi-registry-framework-1.15.0.jar!/org/apache/nifi/registry/db/DatabaseMetadataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain connection from Flyway DataSource
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flyway' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.flywaydb.core.Flyway]: Factory method 'flyway' threw exception; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain connection from Flyway DataSource

registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file nio:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db [1.4.199/1]

registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not open file nio:/opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db [1.4.199/1]
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:883)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:179)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:390)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:3343)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:162)
registry_container_persistent   |   ... 143 common frames omitted
registry_container_persistent   | Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi-registry/nifi-registry-current/database/nifi-registry-primary.mv.db (Permission denied)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
registry_container_persistent   |   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:124)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.store.fs.FileNio.<init>(FilePathNio.java:43)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathNio.open(FilePathNio.java:23)
registry_container_persistent   |   at org.h2.mvstore.FileStore.open(FileStore.java:153)
registry_container_persistent   |   ... 146 common frames omitted
registry_container_persistent   | 2023-06-16 09:17:06,889 INFO [main] o.e.j.a.AnnotationConfiguration Scanning elapsed time=23ms
registry_container_persistent   | Received trapped signal, beginning shutdown...
registry_container_persistent exited with code 0
nifi_container_persistent exited with code 0
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Enter the running container with `docker exec -it nifi_container_persistent sh` and check it.

Comment: Another vote for "does the file eixst?":
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs/nifi-user.log (Permission denied)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify the `user` tag in the docker-compose too.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    registry:
        image: apache/nifi-registry:latest
        container_name: nifiregistry
        hostname: nifiregistry
        user: root
```

```
version: "3.7"
services:    
    nifi:
        image: apache/nifi:1.20.0
        user: root
```

As from my understanding when the user is not specified the internal user of the NiFi tool is `nifi`